# Correct Position For Specific Code, Controller, Model or somewhere else

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have started learning C# MVC 5 for a Room Inventory project i am working on where i work.
I am using active directory to authenticate users and then store these details in a database so that i can then assign users to rooms and tenancies that have items assigned to them.

I used the stock MVC 5 template that comes with Visual Studio 2013 as i only have a month to do the project coming in to it with no previous knowledge and dont have the time to code a fancy looking html / css front end and am relying on the look that comes out of the box.

I have written some code that once a user successfully logged on using form authentication linked with AD it runs a check to see if a user exists in the database, if not it creates one, if it does, it checks to see if it has been set to inactive and reactivates it if needed.

I have placed this code in the AccountController under the login httppost action. As i am new to MVC i wanted to check to see if this is the correct position, or if i should create a new class for this functionality, or if it should be in the model area where i create the database using entity framework code first. What is the best practice?

Here is the code and thanks in advance for any help. I apologize for the long winded post and less than stellar code. Dont hold back with any criticism as i would rather get it right now than make mistakes again and again.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // Put this method in place to allow multiple domains for login. References Web.config for providers
        MembershipProvider domainProvider;
        switch (model.Domain)
        {
            case "Student":
                domainProvider = Membership.Providers["studentADMembershipProvider"];
                break;
            case "Staff":
                domainProvider = Membership.Providers["staffADMembershipProvider"];
                break;
            default:
                throw (new Exception("This domain is not supported"));
        }


        // Method for authenticating users on AD to allow system integration and also add or update user in Users Database
        if (domainProvider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);


            //Code for creating new user based on successfull logged in user.

            //define which domain to link too. otherwise will always default to staff
            PrincipalContext myContext;
            if (model.Domain == "Staff")
            {
                myContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "staff.domain.com");
            }
            else
            {
                myContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "student.domain.com");
            }
            UserPrincipal aduser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(myContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, model.UserName);

            //Check for existence of user with username that matches loged in user
            var userSearch = db.Users.Count(b => b.Username == aduser.SamAccountName);
            if (userSearch == 0)
            {
                // User does not exist, therefore create user
                User user = new User()
                {
                    IsActive = 1,
                    Username = aduser.SamAccountName,
                    FirstName = aduser.GivenName,
                    LastName = aduser.Surname,
                    Extension = aduser.VoiceTelephoneNumber,
                    Email = aduser.EmailAddress,
                    UserTypeId = 3
                };
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                // User does exist, but has been deactivated, therefore reactivate
                var activateUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Username == aduser.SamAccountName);
                if (activateUser.IsActive == 0)
                {
                    activateUser.IsActive = 1;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //db.Users(activateUser.UserId).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }


            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: I would personally encapsulate all of your database activity, I don't think your controller action should be that big. Move all of your database saving etc into another layer and hide the implementation detail away from the controller (since it does not need to know). You should have really taken a look at the default Identity 2.0 framework. That would of assisted you a lot.

Comment: Basically what Jamie said - you should not use the database directly in your account controller. Take a look at the default ASP.NET account controller that gets generated - it uses **UserManager** and **SignInManager** for user operations.

Comment: Thank you both for your swift replies, they are much appreciated. Im now going to go away and have a read about some of the concepts mentioned. Ive taken a look at the classes in the default asp.net site. Following that, to crate a new layer would i create a new class in the App_Data folder and move methods to that class?

Comment: Returning to this old question i asked over two years now for anyone else looking for answers, there is a really good blog post that goes into detail regarding the structure of a monolithic ASP.NET MVC applications: [ASP.NET MVC Solution Architecture – Best Practices](https://chsakell.com/2015/02/15/asp-net-mvc-solution-architecture-best-practices/) This blog post details how to split out database interaction, service layer and controller\view logic and i would recommend anyone curious to take a look.